# Why does the rotation of my keyframes not get saved?

Tags: animation, keyframes

So, I'm new to Blender and currently working on my second ever turnaround of a low-poly model.

I've selected the object, set a keyframe range from 1 to 100.
Added one rotation keyframe on frame 1 and one on frame 100, set their interpolation to linear.
I'm trying to get the object to make one full turn by setting Z to 360° on frame 100. [image]

But! After I enter the 360° (or anything, for that matter) and move away from the keyframe, it goes back to the default 0°. [image]
Does anyone know what the problem here is and how I can get the rotation to stay like I put it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Can you provide file and exact steps to follow along?  Probably not directly related to your question, but you're walking awfully close to gimbal lock here.

Comment: Maybe this is it: are you keyframing at 100 *before* changing the rotation?  You need to change the rotation before keyframing.  The keyframe registers the rotation you have set.  Changing the rotation afterwards doesn't change the keyframed rotation. 
 Move to 100, rotate, keyframe, that order.

Comment: @Nathan that was it!! i set the keyframe and then changed the rotation - now i tried changing the rotation first and then creating the keyframe, which works. thank you!